# can't start the MediaPlayer again after stop method of MediaPlayeris called

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In this application I have 2 buttons one is for start the media player and another one is for stop the media player ,But in my case stat and stop is working fine .

I can't start the media player once the stop button is clicked and also I got

```
start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x9f5d8300)
    error (-38, 0)
```

I tried some solutions from stackoverflow but nothing is helped .

Coding :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mStop);
        mStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mStart);

        final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarmsong);

        mStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player.start();
                player.setLooping(true);
                player.setVolume(100, 100);
            }
        });
        mStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player.stop();
            }
        });
    }
```

can anyone help me to fix it .

Comment: See this doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer you need player.prepare() "Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the Prepared state again."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read the doc they say you need to call prepare() method to reset your player.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mStop);
    mStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mStart);

    final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarmsong);

    mStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player.start();
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.setVolume(100, 100);
        }
    });
    mStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            player.stop();
            player.prepare();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do

```
player.release();
```

after stopping media player

Comment: ok then try like this

mStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player.pause();
            }
        });

Comment: and before starting and pause mediaplayer  you should add media player null check otherwise your app will crash if media player is null